# Is my convergence proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It's "obvious" that the following sequence converges. I was asked to prove it on a homework assignment and was given no credit for my proof. I wanted to ask the community here if 1) they think my proof is correct, and 2) if it isn't, what exactly is wrong with it. How would you prove it?

Here is the sequence:

$a_1 = 0.1,\; a_2 = 0.12,\; a_3 = 0.123,\; \cdots,\; a_{11} = 0.1234567891011,\; \cdots,\; a_n = 0.123\cdots n$.

Here is my proof that it converges:

Let $b_m = 0.d_1d_2d_3\cdots d_m$ for $m, i, d_i \in \mathbb{N} : 0 \leq d_i \leq 9$ and $1 \leq i \leq m$. This is the decimal representation of 
$${d_1 \over 10^1} + {d_2 \over 10^2} + {d_3 \over 10^3} + \cdots + {d_m \over 10^m}.$$
$\{b_m\}$ is bounded, which we'll show in a moment by induction, and monotone increasing. Therefore it converges by the monotone convergence theorem. Since $d_i$ is ANY digit $0$ through $9$, $\{b_m\}$ converges $\Rightarrow \{a_n\}$ converges.

Let $P(m)$ be the statement $0 \leq b_m < 1$. $P(1)$ is $0 \leq {d_1 \over 10} < 1,$ which is true since $0 \leq d_1 < 10$. Now we'll show $P(m) \Rightarrow P(m+1)$. It follows from the definition of decimal representations and from $P(m)$ that $1 - b_m \geq {1 \over 10^m}$, which is the same as $b_m + {1 \over 10^m} \leq 1$. But $(0 \leq {d_{m+1} \over 10^{m+1}} < {1 \over 10^m}) \Leftrightarrow (0 \leq {d_{m+1} \over 10} < 1) \Leftrightarrow (0 \leq d_{m+1}  < 10)$. So $0 \leq b_m + {d_{m+1} \over 10^{m+1}} = b_{m+1} \leq 1$, which is $P(m+1)$. Therefore $\{b_m\}$ is bounded.

To see that $\{b_m\}$ is monotone increasing, note that its inductive definition is $b_{m + 1} = b_m + {d_{m+1} \over 10^{m+1}},$ where $b_1 = {d_1 \over 10}$. We showed above that ${d_{m+1} \over 10^{m+1}} > 0 \; \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, so it follows that $b_{m+1} > b_{m} \; \forall m$. This concludes the proof that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Comment: The main problem I see is that from your definition, each $b_m$ is not a number, it is actually a set of numbers since each $d_i$ is allowed to vary. However given no credit was a little bit harsh :(